# If there anyway i can check if the cell contains the result of a arrayformula()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

For example i have this in A1 :

```
=arrayformula(B1:B100)
```

If in A10 i accidentally enter a value (which will overlap with arrayformula result) , it will produce error in the A1 because of existing value. But is there anyway if i want to flag this  cell A10 with conditional formatting?

For example if i enter " " (space) , all the cells will be blank without me knowing which one is has problem, except if i check error notification. So in big sheet matrix it's faster for me to spot by coloring the cell.

How can i tell if the A10 has a non-formula value or the result of arrayformula() in A1 ?

isformula() only works if there's a formula in A10 not as as the result of arrayformula().

Comment: Hi. Good question. There's been some discussion of this topic over the years. Would you please edit your question to summarise your research on this topic (mainly so we don't re-invent the wheel). On a tangent, have you read [How to use ISFORMULA with ARRAYFORMULA?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/29615676/how-to-use-isformula-with-arrayformula?hl=en) from "Docs Editor Help"; it's dated Feb 2020 but there is a work-around that might help in your case.